# ExtJS 4 display MS Word text

Tags: extjs

I have to display a MS World text (about 150 pages) in a ExtJS panel (in modal window I have two tabs, the first is a picture and the second should be the picture description). 
I can prepare thix text olso in PDF format but stil have no idea how to do it good.

Comment: You can easily render a pdf in a div using https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe tag defines a rectangular region within the document in which the browser can display a separate document.

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel' {
   width: 400,
   height: 600,
   modal   : true,
   items: [{ 
             xtype: 'component',
            html : '<iframe src="give path to your pdf here" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>',
         }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is **xtype: uxiframe**. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.IFrame

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
   width: 400,
   height: 600,
   modal   : true,
   layout:'fit',
   items: [{ 
        xtype: 'uxiframe',
        title: 'myPDF title',
        src: 'path to your pdf'
   }]
}).show();
```

For see another way to use this component (with fiddle) take a look at this: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299797-Ext-ux-IFrame